# Read AppSettings from a secondary webconfig

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I created a second web config and placed it in a folder:

~/Configuration/OtherConnections.config

My config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="serverurl" value="http://serverUrl" />
    <add key="UserName" value="myUser" />
    <add key="Password" value="XXXXXXX" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

When I attempt to read the value from one of the items like:

```
string connectionInfo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
```

I do not get a value back. Is this because the web config is in a folder, or is there something else going on in this web app?

Comment: What gave you the idea you could do this?

Comment: Your `otherConnections.config` should be in a parent directory of your webform in order to use it.

Answer (score 5):

> I do not get a value back. Is this because the web config is in a folder ... ?

No, not the folder but the filename. You can use `~/Configuration/Web.config` but then you have to explicity open it:

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/Configuration");
```

And then to read from it:

```
string url  = config.AppSettings.Settings["serverurl"].Value;
```

Note that you cannot specify (and thus not change) the actual `web.config` file name. Just the folder.

Answer (score 2):

you can have only one `web.config` file for each web folder

There are tow options anyway:

- In the IIS Manager you need to configure the sub folder as a new application. It uses the   web.config file from the running app.
- Another option is using a single config file and adding a `<location>` section to segment the file to act differently for some folders or files. (which I would suggest more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx))

Comment: A Web application can have 1 web.config for each folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can access multiple config files by using WebConfigurationmanager method. add namespace:

```
using System.Web.Configuration;
```

So, to access the appSettings of

`../SomeProjectFolder/Environment/Web.config`, you can do:

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/SomeProjectFolder/Environment/");
string username = config.AppSettings.Settings["username"].Value;
```

Hope this helps.